# An event to respond to element growth

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say you have a very typical web application - maybe an SPA - and it downloads contents via AJAX. You also have a footer, whose position you control via JavaScript.

Now your content is downloaded via AJAX and a lot o new HTML is inserted, and the page body grows way beyond your viewport.

As expected, your footer no longer needs to stick to the bottom of the screen but can simply become part of the page itself.

What even can someone use to fire the re-position callback, when the body grows in height? I am just speaking of linear growth in height - not through animations or anything - but when the height property actually changes.

Answer (score 0):

On AJAX success,

```
var footer = document.getElementById(footerId);
footer.style.position = "static";
```